# $(this) inside data() function call?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How an access to the **current object inside the call** to `data()` or maybe any other jQuery function:

```
$('#newVisitors').data('options', $.extend($('#newVisitors').data('options'), {
   property : 'value'
}));
```

avoiding repeating of `$('#newVisitors')` selector?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should store the jQuery object in a variable first;

```
var self = $('#newVisitors');

self.data('options', $.extend(self.data('options'), {
   property : 'value'
}));
```

Edit: If you want to use `$(this)`;

```
$('#newVisitors').each(function () {
    $(this).data('options', $.extend($(this).data('options'), {
       property : 'value'
    }));
});
```

Comment: Yep, this is quite obvious, there is no other way?

Comment: Adding an useless variable and think about its name :P kidding, that's fine, but it would be better if $(this) context was the element itself...

Comment: If you really want `$(this)` to be the element itself then see my update, but I don't see that method as a *better* solution.

Comment: thanks for your edits. I think it's not better too, because #newVisitors will always contain just one element. Thanks anyway.